# Ошибка при попытке получить данные с OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, access, oledb

Пишу код для копирования данных с файлов Access и Excel в другую БД.
Драйверы для работы с провайдером OLE взял с официального сайта Microsoft, так называемые Access Database Engine для x64 платформы (пишу под Windows 7 x64).

Код:

```
...
var values = new object[fieldsNum];

while (reader.Read())
{
    reader.GetValues(values);
}
...
```

Где `reader` - уже проинициализированный `IDataReader` (`OleDbDataReader`).

При попытке осуществить чтение из `reader` вываливается exception:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'IRowset'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call
>   on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '{0C733A7C-2A1C-11CE-ADE5-00AA0044773D}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Для других `DataReader`'ов код работает (`SqlServer`, `MySql`).

Пытался установить 32-битные драйвера OleDb - программа вообще их не видит, так как компиляция под x64.

Comment: В каком потоке вы создаете ридер и в каком его используете?

Comment: @andreycha, В потоке основного окна создается ридер, в потоке BackgroundWorker'а (DoWork) используется

Comment: Если создание и чтение ридера идет в одном потоке, то ошибка отсутсвует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попытка создания и вызова COM-компонента из разных апартаментов (STA/MTA) может приводить к ошибками маршалинга.

При создании экземпляра `OleDbDataReader` в UI потоке, вы создаете его в STA апартаменте. При вызове методов с помощью `BackgroundWorker`, вы вызываете его из MTA апартамента (из пула потоков).

[Разъяснения от Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/kbview/313510) насчет `OleDbDataReader`:

> Используйте объект OleDb из того же STA апартамента, в котором он был
>   создан. Либо из любого MTA апартамента, если он был создан в MTA.